# Laravel Getting Error When Running Tinker

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, tinker

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and PHP 7.1, but I get an error when I'm trying to use Tinker.

When I run:

```
php artisan tinker
```

I get the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError] Call to
>   undefined function Laravel\Tinker\tap()

I upgraded my Laravel from 5.2 to 5.5, but most of my previous functionality doesn't work. I reverted to 5.2, but I am still getting this error.

Comment: Laravel 5.2 require PHP 5 or higher but lower than 7. Infact PHP 7 introduces some breaking changes that conflicts with Laravel 5.2. Try to use a lower version of PHP

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into the same error with Lumen 5.2, while trying to use the laravel/tinker package. The tap function is a helper function from the  illuminate/support package but it looks like it was introduced in version 5.4. See: https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/v5.4.0/helpers.php#L855